# Trying to make an information tour guide app for my school but the mapKit keeps on failing

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mapkit, xcode8

I am trying to make an app for my school. I am making it in a master-detail application. I have done everything for the information side of the app, however, the map part is something I am struggling with. I have looked online to help me with this problem however everyone is using the single page application. I tried to make the app on the single page application but again still no luck.

What I am trying to do is set a region around my school, and add annotations but when I do the code and everything is correct and there are no errors, I run the app and then will press the button to go to the map page, where it will be zoomed at looking at a country and no region has been set or any annotations.

I am using Xcode 8, Swift 3 language.

If anybody has some advice or knows that there is some extra code I need to input that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yo @Jo5h - Can you add some of your code to your question, its easier to see whats wrong if you do :)